# CSS - Cannot change table width

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

Please refer to my website: http://ballsohard.co.uk/fishfilet/

Use the login section at the top of the page with any input you wish.

Click the inbox button (it's the yellow one)

I want the table (id: "inboxtab") to have a width which runs across the content area. I have tried to do this by setting the table width to 100% but it is having no effect.

```
#inboxtab   {
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:11px;
display: none;     (ignore this line)
width: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I inspected your page with firebug, and found that the table has an inline style declaration: `display: inline;`:

```
<table id="inboxtab" style="display: inline;">
    <!-- This is your table -->
</table>
```

It's not possible to set the `width` property on *inline elements*.
So, you have to remove this declaration.

Comment: By default the table is hidden with display: none, clicking the button changes the display state. 

is there any way to set the table width still using this technique?

Comment: you're welcome... if it worked make my answer the Answer, will serve to others in the future

Comment: `display:table;` solved my problem, replace the `inline-block`. Thanks.